# how to add function for closing and opening bet per match smart contract?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

source code:https://github.com/laronlineworld/bettingMatch/blob/main/bettingMatch.sol

How to open and close bet per match

```
function bet(uint16 _matchSelected, uint16 _resultSelected) public payable {

  //Check if the player already exist
//   require(!checkIfPlayerExists(msg.sender));

  //Check if the value sended by the player is higher than the min value
  require(msg.value >= minimumBet);
  
  //Set the player informations : amount of the bet, match and result selected
  playerInfo[msg.sender].amountBet = msg.value;
  playerInfo[msg.sender].matchSelected = _matchSelected;
  playerInfo[msg.sender].resultSelected = _resultSelected;
  
  //Add the address of the player to the players array
  players.push(msg.sender);

  //Finally increment the stakes of the team selected with the player bet
  if ( _resultSelected == 1){
      totalBetHome[_matchSelected] += msg.value;
  }
  else if( _resultSelected == 2){
      totalBetAway[_matchSelected] += msg.value;
  }
  else{
      totalBetDraw[_matchSelected] += msg.value;
  }

}
```

This is the code for opening the betting

```
/* Function to enable betting */
function beginVotingPeriod()  public onlyOwner returns(bool) {
    bettingActive = true;
    return true;
}
```

how about opening the bet per match?

also closing the bet per match

```
/* Function to close voting and handle payout. Can only be called by the owner. */
function closeVoting() public onlyOwner returns (bool) {
    // Close the betting period
    bettingActive = false;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The linked code recognizes a match as index of these arrays: `totalBetHome`, `totalBetAway` and `totalBetDraw`.

You can add a mapping where the key is the match ID, and the value is a flag signalizing whether there's a betting enabled on the match or not.

```
// default value for each is `false`
mapping (uint256 => bool) isMatchEnabled;

function enableBetting(uint256 _matchId) external onlyOwner {
    isBettingEnabled[_matchId] = true;
}

function disableBetting(uint256 _matchId) external onlyOwner {
    isBettingEnabled[_matchId] = false;
}
```

Then you can amend the `bet()` function - add a condition requiring betting for this match to be enabled.

```
function bet(uint16 _matchSelected, uint16 _resultSelected) public payable {
    require(isBettingEnabled[_matchSelected] == true);

    // rest of your code
}
```

---

*Note: Solidity v0.4.2 that you're using in the linked code, is few years old and has few security issues. The current version (August 2021) is 0.8.7. Consider upgrading to the latest version.*

Comment: Thank you, Can you assist mo with this problem? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/107680/how-to-bet-on-multiple-matches-using-one-address-applying-mapping